# Выводит ошибку отсутствия на сайте json, как обойти эту ошибку, чтоб выводить где есть json, а где не присутствует json?

Tags: json

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bisne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bisne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bisne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bisne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Games\новое.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(response.json())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bisne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: хотел задать - задай. Тут и подсказка имеется, как правильно это делать - [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что веб-сайт не вернул никаких json данных, вы можете это обработать блоком try/except:

```
try:
    print(response.json())
except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
    print('JSON ответ пуст')
```

Comment: Прости за такую глупую ошибку, я впредь буду внимательнее